# How to detect number in input between two dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have atypical problem. I need to detect specific type of number/record which is typed in some text input. Structure which i'm trying to catch looks like that: `.9.` or `.2.` or `.number.`. So, what i have is some kind of ways/trys to do this but none of them doesn't work:

`var target = input[type='text'];`

```
target.val() === '.' + /^[0-9]+$/ +'.' ?
   console.log('true') :
   console.log('false');


target.val() === '.' + parseInt(10) +'.' ?
   console.log('true') :
   console.log('false');


target.val().indexOf('.'+ RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/) +'.') >=0 ?
   console.log('true') :
   console.log('false');
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Single digit, or multiple?

Comment: You cannot add a regex and a string like that but you can build a dynamic regex with the constructor. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info on how to use it.

Comment: While this may be valid JavaScript: `var target = input[type='text'];`, I doubt it does what you expect it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to use regex, you can use the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method for this.

```
var target = '.123.'
console.log(/^\.\d+\.$/.test(target)) // true
```

Regular Expression:

```
^         # the beginning of the string
 \.       #   '.'
 \d+      #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
 \.       #   '.'
$         # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: `$` only matches before `\n` if the multiline flag is used, which you didn't.

Comment: @gilly3 No need to use the multi-line modifier here.

Comment: Right.  Your code comment says "before an optional \n", but that's not accurate since you aren't using the multiline flag.  I don't mean to be overly pedantic.